# How to verify a text in custom dialog in wix installer?

Tags: windows, wix, windows-installer

For my product, I am using the wix installer and there I am using custom UI dialog. In that dialog, I have a control of type Edit, where I am taking user's IP value. Now I want to verify that when user press next, installer should verify the input.

So I am wondering how can I do it?

I found few examples with CDATA, where they are checking product key, but I am unable to apply it with my question, so any leads for the same ?

Here is my snippet for just taking value and proceeding without any check:

```
 <Control Id="NameEdit" Type="Edit" X="45" Y="85" Width="220" Height="18" Property="IPVAL" Text="{80} " />
 <Control Id="Next" Type="PushButton" X="236" Y="243" Width="56" Height="17" Default="yes" Text="&amp;Next">
          <Publish Event="ValidateProductID" Value="0">1</Publish>
          <Publish Event="SpawnWaitDialog" Value="WaitForCostingDlg">CostingComplete = 1</Publish>
          <Publish Event="EndDialog" Value="Return" Order="2">ProductID</Publish>
        </Control>
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear how CDATA is connected to the question, or whether you've tried anything specific, but in general you need to publish a DoAction event that calls a custom action. In that custom action you get hold of the property value and validate it. Validation usually results in setting some other property saying that validation succeeded. Then you can disable the Next control if the validation failed, together with an error message.

The example seems pretty thorough, but if it isn't then ask a more specific question:

https://www.firegiant.com/wix/tutorial/events-and-actions/control-your-controls/